# How to change and get objects from aother class without declaring it?

Tags: java, class, scope

I am new to java. I try to get and change objects from a class ( ex: Class Camera or Class Microphone and objects camera1, camera2, camera3 , microphone1, microphone2, microphone3 in their classes each with price, name, score ) i want to get the name of one object and change one's price from another class without making a new one.

This is the first class:

```
public class Microphone{
String name;
int price;
/** Constructors, setters and getters */

Microphone mic1 = new Microphone("mic1",200);
Microphone mic2 = new Microphone("mic2",300);}
```

This is the second class:

```
public class Camera{
String name;
int price;
/** Constructors, setters and getters */
Camera cam1 = new Camera("cam1",500);
Camera cam2 = new Camera("cam2",1000);}
```

In the main class ( or in a different class like Shop, menu etc ) i want to get the price of one's object, like cam1.getPrice and mic2.setPrice so i can compare to the stats of the player in the game if he can afford it and to change the price of it.

Comment: Create *setters* and *getters* and use them.

Comment: I observed that with getters and setters i need to make a new object in that class. I want the objects to be passes between classes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you will want to make your class 'static'. That way, only one instance of the class exists in memory, and there is not need to create any instance in your main.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ArrayList in your Main class with your object type and manage them this way. You can then modify your objects as much as you'd like. If you create an interface class you can do something like this:
First create the interface class, I named mine Device and gave it one method, to set the cost. You can add whatever methods you need to add, like setDate, setModel, setName.... etc

```
public interface Device
{
    void setCost(double costIn);
}
```

Next create the microphone class and have it implement Device. After, you will need to add the Device methods to the class.

```
public class Microphone implements Device
{
    double cost = 0.0;

    public void setCost(double costIn)
    {
        cost = costIn;

    }

}
```

Here is another class example with Camera, also with one data member.

```
public class Camera implements Device
{

    double cost = 0.0;

    public void setCost(double costIn)
    {
        cost = costIn;

    }

    }
```

Now in your main class, you can have all of your Devices into one ArrayList for easy manipulation and control.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            ArrayList<Device> arr = new ArrayList<Device>();
            arr.add(new Microphone());
            arr.add(new Camera());
        }
```

Honestly there is a lot of ways to go about what you are asking, this is just one example.

Comment: What i do when I want to modify or get a field of one object in "arr" ArrayList. And if i declare it in main, i still need to declare it in other classes?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class(It is also known as model class) such as Car.
- Then define relevent attributes inside that class.
- Put the full args constructor.
- Make setters & getters.

  ```
  public class Car {
   private String name;

   Car(String name){
      this name=name; 
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
  ```

  }

> So you can change or get on created object using getters & setters.
>   example : Car c1= new Car("Audi"); If you want to change name of Car
>   c1.setName("Toyota");

Comment: I can't acces one object's field that was declared in other class from another class.